# Authorize microphone for wildcard subdomain in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, permissions, chromium

How can I authorize a wildcard subdomain for microphone access? My company uses domains like `chat.client1.companyname.com` and `talk.QA2.companyname.com` for its videoconference software. It’s extremely annoying having to approve microphone access to each and every subdomain separately.

How can I get Chrome to authorize `*.companyname.com` for microphone access so I am not bombarded with permissions pop-ups throughout my day? There seems to be some use of subdomains for load-balancing, so it’s not like the problem slowly goes away once I’ve approved more or less all the subdomains I’d use on a regular basis.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to authorize the sites one by one.

Chrome used to have in the page
*Settings > Privacy and security > Site Settings > Microphone* two
"Add" buttons with which you could add websites and even use
wildcards. However, these buttons have now disappeared.

Comment: So there is no acceptable answer, then?

Comment: Rather a negative answer, but someone else may know something.